# Show Relative Path Only on Search Results

Tags: search-results

I've been searching for quite some time but I can't find a good guide on how I can do this (or maybe I'm using the wrong query)

I want to remove the domain name from the URL that is displayed on search results. In other words, I only what the relative path to be displayed.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You´ll have to edit the display-template for the requested item.

altough I don´t see a reason why to Display a relative path to "normal" users.

Comment: My problem really is with the BCS Profile Pages. They show the port (e.g. sharepoint.com:443/page.aspx) Which is kind of annoying for me.